# как давать аргумент тегу через JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<p id="img"></p>
localStorage.setItem('img1',JSON.stringify(img1.getAttribute('src')));
let wr=document.getElementById('img');
let t=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('img1'));
wr=document.write(`<img src=????????`);
```

когда я возьму из local storage ссылку на картинку и храну его за переменной t потом как я могу этот аргумент передавать на src там где вопросительние знаки

Comment: а как выглядит сам объект в переменной `t`?

Comment: images/home/gallery1.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предположим, что `t` выглядит так:

```
{ "img": "images/1.jpg" }
```

Тогда ссылку можно вставить так:

```
wr=document.write(`<img src=${t.img}`);
```

если в `t` просто строка, то так:

```
wr=document.write(`<img src=${t}`);
```

Примеры:

```js
let t = { "img": "images/1.jpg" }
document.write(`<img src=${t.img}`);
```

```js
let t = "images/1.jpg"
document.write(`<img src=${t}`);
```

Comment: огромное спасибо через 7 минут приму ответ